# Is there any possibility in ssrs to show matrix below the chart(no gap between chart and matrix) when execution occures?

Tags: matrix, charts, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, msbi

We have developed a ssrs report based on client requirement,in which we used 6 charts and 16 matrices.

we placed one chart on another chart in same one place.space below the charts is allocated to matrices.

But for matrices, in designing, we placed one matrix below another matrix(The gap between matrices are 1pt and it is the minimum gap between two matrices to identify.if gap is 0pt, then over lapping of matrices occured.)

Reports having multiple parameters like interval(yearly,monthly,halfyearly,quarterly),filtertypes,reporttypes,types .

Based on selection of values in above paramters,only one chart and one matrix will show data.

I have attached design image(showing no gap between charts and matrices,matrix to matrix) and image after report execution.

But, in report exuction, there is much more gap existing  between chart and matrix for some selection of paramter values (my opinion is,some time the last matrix executed to display the data)

But when executing report, client don't want gap between chart and matrix for any filter selections.

already we applied expressions on charts visibility condition and matrices visibility condition to display them based on required paramter conditions .
We are using visual studio 2015 and sql server 2016

Is there any possibility in ssrs to show matrix below the chart(no gap between chart and matrix) when execution occures?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF9va.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4YcI.png)

Comment: Have you tried setting the report property ConsumeContainerwhitespace to true?
Other option is to put them both in a rectangle and test. SSRS is very fiddly when it comes to such layout

Comment: Consume container white space property not worked for my report.But adding rectangular works.Thanks Harry

Comment: Great to hear. Can you please accept the same answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the report property ConsumeContainerwhitespace to true?
Other option is to put them both in a rectangle and test. SSRS is very fiddly when it comes to such layout